# How to change date of Kendo MVC Scheduler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I used kendo scheduler to show users events. There is a date dropdown user select dropdown and I bind data.
I want to also set current date of scheduler to user selected data.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<CalendarItem>()
    .Name("scheduler")
    .Date(DateTime.Now) // Want to change this like ViewBag.Date
    .StartTime(DateTime.Now)
    .Events(e =>
    {
        e.Edit("scheduler_edit");
        e.Remove("scheduler_delete");
    })
    .Views(views => views.MonthView(x => x.Selected(true)))
    .Timezone("Etc/UTC")
    .DataSource(d => d
        .Model(m =>
        {
            m.Field(f => f.Title);
            m.Field(f => f.Description);
        })
        .Read(x => x.Action("Read", "Reminder"))
    )
)
```

I tried .Date(ViewBag.Date) but not worked.

Please help me.

Comment: Actually your question was an answer to my problem - how to default the scheduler to today... .Date(DateTime.Now) THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

This work for me:

`.Date((DateTime)ViewBag.StartTime)`